# Trying to add a new feature in my wordpress website

Tags: plugins, posts

I have a website called NearFile. Here is the link: https://nearfile.com/. It is a software downloading website created on WordPress. On every software page I have added a sidebar called "Other Versions" of the current software. Now I want to add a link after the "Other Versions" section like "View all versions", which will take users to another page like: **website.com/post-slug/versions** . But how I will do that? I have searched google about it. But I have not found any solutions.

Any Solution?

Here is the code that I have used in "Other Versions" sidebar:

```
<?php

                        $title = get_the_title();
                        $args = array("post_type" => "post", "title" => $title, "posts_per_page" => 10);
                        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <div class="row soft_sm_list">
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <?php
                                            if (get_field("software_logo")){?>
                                                <img src="<?php the_field("software_logo");?>" width="24" height="24" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <?php
                                            }else{?>
                                                <span class="soft_thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></span><?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-10 soft_meta">
                                        <h3 class="h6"><?php the_title(); ?> <?php the_field( "software_version" );?></h3>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <?php 
                        endwhile;
                        }else{
                            echo "Sorry, we have only one version for this software.";
                        }
                        wp_reset_query();

                        ?>
```

In this I have created a query of same post titles and shown a list of them with their versions. I have used ACF plugin to add the version of each post.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add the code you used to add the "Other Version" into the right sidebar?

Comment: Hey I have added the code in my question as StackOverflow doesn't allows to add more than 500 characters. You can check it from there.